# MORPHO FINGER PRINT INSTALLATION IN 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my laptop and for official purposes I need  to use finger print scanner with State Government for administration.  I am having KEDIA GROUP MSO 1300 E3 device with me.  can I get the commands for installation and for use in my laptop

Comment: Have you checked with the manufacturer of the fingerprint scanner to make sure that the device is supported under linux?  Do they make a linux driver?

Comment: I also need to use such device for Aadhaar related registration of eGov India. Did you find a driver?
I found this device and it's brochure says linux is supported:
file:///Users/harshjain/Downloads/MFS100.pdf

Comment: Sorry, this is the correct url: https://www.mantratec.com/products/Fingerprint-Sensors/MFS100-Fingerprint-Scanner